# Need a message when Active is not equal to No on PHP Delete File

Tags: php, mysql

If you try to delete an object when active = "Yes" I want an error message to let the user know why they can't delete the record. With my current code, if active is "No" it just gives them a blank screen, no explanation to why it is not being deleted. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
try{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM projects WHERE id=$id AND active='No'";
    $pdo->exec($sql);

    echo "Record cannot be deleted";
    }else {
    echo "Records were deleted successfully.";
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
```

Comment: `try { } else { } catch(...) { }` is invalid PHP. The syntax is `try {} catch(...) { }`.

Comment: Where is the "if" statement?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.